# Force updating Cocoapod with same tag

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm working on a private cocoapod and project using that cocoapod concurrently, and I'm having difficulty settling on the right workflow for keeping everything synchronized.

The problem i am encountering is this: If i make a change to my cocoapod project, I've found that the only way I can get my other project to pull those changes is if I create a new tag and change the version referenced by the pod spec. As a result, I'm getting stuck with many useless versions of my pod spec.

What I would prefer is to simply move my tag to the head of my cocoapod project and somehow re-pull the cocoapod. I've found that pod install and pod update do not seem to refresh the cocoapod in this circumstance.

Does anyone have any recommendations for concurrently working on a cocoapod and a project that uses it?

Comment: When this happens to me I usually just remove the line from my `Podfile`, run `pod install`, re-add the line and re-run `pod install`. Maybe there is a better way but this one is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `:head` flag but you would still have to create the tags.

```
pod 'YourPod', :head
```

When running `pod update` the pod’s latest version spec would be used.

Comment: ```[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] `:head` dependencies have been removed. Please use normal external source dependencies (`:git => 'GIT_REPO_URL'`) instead of `:head` ```

Answer (score 6):

We do the same internally in our team and we ended up by referencing the latest commit, instead of the tag.
Here you've an example of a podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "TTFacebook"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "Tiltap wrapper around Facebook SDK 3.5"
  s.homepage     = "https://bitbucket.org/*****"
  s.license      = 'MIT'
  s.author       = { "Paolo Tagliani" => "p.tagliani@tiltap.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, '5.0'
  s.source       = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org.*****", :commit => "a8c276eec3372f2b088de0731a7808e4766b625d" }
  s.source_files  = 'TTFacebook/TTFacebook/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK','~>3.5'

end
```

Every time that we modify something in our library, we update our podspec with the latest commit.

Answer (score 3):

If you just point your podfile at your library's git repo it will just pull the default branch's latest.

`pod 'InternalStuff', :git => 'https://github.com/YourGithub/InternalStuff.git'`

Comment: It will pull the latest commit the first time, but if you push something new after and you rerun pod install, it wont work. You have to run pod update after.

Answer (score 0):

@Emilie's comment is a way better solution than the other offered answers for this question. Here is her comment on the OP question in case you missed it.

> When this happens to me I usually just remove the line from my Podfile, run pod install, re-add the line and re-run pod install. Maybe there is a better way but this one is pretty simple.