# How to force CocoaPods to use the latest release for a Github repo?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to create my first `CocoaPods` [Printer](https://cocoapods.org/pods/printer-logger). I have gone through all the steps which are required to create your own. This is the [latest](https://github.com/hemangshah/printer/releases/tag/1.0) release version to which I want my pod to point. But somehow the pod is pointing to some other version which I have deleted to overcome "duplicate entry" error. What should I do to force CocoaPods to use the latest release available? For a note, if you could check the pod on the CocoaPods it has a difference of "stars" received for the repo. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

This is the [Podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/0/0/printer-logger/1.0/printer-logger.podspec.json) file for that repo.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your repo.
Go to Terminal then enter:
`pod repo update --verbose`
--verbose is used to show everything happening on the terminal.
after the update finishes try `pod install`
**ScreenShot of the class**
[Printer.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgqwF.png)

Comment: did you try adding to your pod file the requested version? _pod 'printer-logger' , '~> 1.0'_

Comment: I used _pod 'printer-logger' , '~> 1.0'_  everything went well.

Comment: try using _pod 'printer-logger', :git => 'https://github.com/hemangshah/printer.git', :tag => '1.0'_ and i will be uploading the screenshot in a while

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot. You have the correct code from the pod installation. I am really amazed that I can't do it here.

Comment: try removing cocoapods and installing it again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, King T. for help through. Finally, I read this comment on this answer,

> When this happens to me I usually just remove the line from my Podfile, run pod install, re-add the line and re-run pod installs. Maybe there is a better way but this one is pretty simple.

And that work for me.

[Force updating Cocoapod with same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551766/force-updating-cocoapod-with-same-tag?rq=1)